# Adding new value to an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have been trying to add a new value pair to an array called products.

This is my array before the loop:

```
"products": [
{
    "id": "050435",
    "name": "Test Product",
    "price": 10,
}
]
```

This is my loop:

```
$item = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $item['new_item'] = 'item_value';
}
$products[] = $item;
```

Now I need to do this as to obtain the 'item_value' I will need to work with the data inside this array to get this value which I can do later. However I get this as a result when I am trying to add this item to this array.

```
"products": [
  {
    "id": "050435",
    "name": "Test Product",
    "price": 10,
  },
  {
    "new_item": "item_value"
  }
]
```

I have tried array_merge and trying $products[0][] etc but I can't get this inside the products array. Any help will be great thanks. This is how I want it to be:

```
"products": [
{
    "id": "050435",
    "name": "Test Product",
    "price": 10,
    "new_item": "item_value"
},
]
```

Comment: `new_item` IS inside the products array. Not sure what you're looking for?

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly you want to get as result as you are getting a perfect result from what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

It should be that simple:

```
$products[0]['new_item'] = 'item_value';
```

If you need this for every product in `$products` array then:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product['new_item'] = 'item_value';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert new value to product array use this code.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    //$item['new_item'] = 'item_value';
    $product['new_item'] = 'item_value';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to loop through the original array of `$products` and add a new array-key to each `$product`.

```
$products = [
    [
        "id"=> "050435",
        "name"=> "Test Product",
        "price"=> 10
    ],[
        "id"=> "012345",
        "name"=> "Test Product 2",
        "price"=> 15
    ]
];

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product['new_item'] = 'item_value';
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($product);
echo "</pre>";
```